# Ruby split at '=' but not at '\='

Tags: ruby, regex, split

In Ruby: How can I split a string at '=' but not at '\='?
Example:

```
    string = "abc = def \= ghi" 
    --> ["abc", "def \\= ghi"]
```

With string.split("=") I get three entries in the Array.

Comment: `"abc = def \= ghi"` is the same as `"abc = def = ghi"`. Therefore, there is nothing that distinguishes `=` and `\=`, and what you ask is impossible.

Comment: Further to @sawa's point, if you want both the string and the second element of the desired array to contain `\\=`, rather than `\=`, please edit your question to make the correction.  If you choose to allow the question to stand as worded, expect downvotes aplenty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired output *exactly* you can also just use the spaces:

```
string.split(" = ")
```

:-)

Comment: The example contains spaces, but there is no mention of spaces being required.  If the code originated as a code fragment, it would not be unusual to see `abc=def`.

Comment: You are correct, one would not *expect* the spaces, but in his example they are *not* part of the split strings in the array. Thats the reason for the smiley anyway.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't think of the blanks ... :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use negative lookbehind to check whether there is no `\` before the `=` sign.

```
string = "abc = def \\= ghi"
print string.split(/(?<!\\)=/).flatten
```

Outputs:

```
["abc ", " def \\= ghi"]
```

Comment: `.flatten` is not needed here, the result of `.split` is already a flat Array.

Answer (score 1):

You can split on

```
(?<!\)=
```

`(?<=...)` is a negative lookbehind.